# Silence = -4 to Notice against Sounds, but what about Notice against Stealth in general?

Tags: stealth, invisibility, hearing, savage-worlds-adventure-edition

Silence gives anyone who tries to hear you -4 to their Notice roll (or an auto-fail with a Raise), but how much does this spell influence your Stealth roll where you also have to stay out of sight?

I am planning on combining Silence (-4/auto-fail to Notice) and Invisibility (-4/-6 to Notice), but I don't know how to combine these numbers. Without the auto-fail I would've just added them up, but the auto-fail gives me the impression that it was intended that I don't do that in general with these spells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically, a raise on silence doesn't give you an additional numerical bonus, but if your stealth roll is based on hearing only (e.g. sneaking past a closed door), then you get an auto-success. Aside from that, you just add the numbers up.

[Source](https://www.pegforum.com/forum/savage-worlds/savage-worlds-general-chat/44194-silence-4-to-notice-against-sound-but-what-about-stealth-in-general)

To quote the source:

> The net result being that Silence always applies a –4 penalty to Notice rolls at least partially based on hearing, but with a raise, it's an auto-fail if the Notice roll is based solely on hearing.

Answer (score 1):

Savage Worlds relies heavily on situational rulings by the GM (that's the entire basis of the Comprehensive Modifiers side bar on page 34).

*Silence* imposes a situational -4 / automatic failure on Notice rolls for sound; not all Notice rolls (it doesn't make observers blind), just Notice rolls for hearing.

Similarly, *invisibility* doesn't affect being heard or smelled or touched, just seen. So, the *invisibility* power affects Notice rolls that rely upon vision and attacks that rely upon vision to accurately locate the character.

These are different situations, so their benefits don't add together. Rather, the character is now extremely difficult to detect in two different situations - sound and sight. Assuming both powers were activated with a Raise, and that *silence* had the Mobile power modifier, then the character **cannot** be heard (all sound-based Notice rolls automatically fail) and is extremely difficult to see (-6 to visual Notice rolls). 
 Which is generally fantastic, but not any help against a bunch of monsters with a sense of smell so keen they can locate targets.

For the corner case where a character has *invisibility* and *silence* (with a Raise) active against alert observers, the situation will dictate the penalties for those observers. If they are only relying upon vision then their Notice rolls are -4/-6; if they are relying only upon sound then they automatically fail; if they are relying upon both then they are only relying upon vision - and modifiers from audio sensors, noise makers, or loud ground would be completely ignored.

A tactically more interesting use of *silence* is to silence the guards and then drop a grenade on them - they die and no one can hear it.

---

For completeness, I should note a commonly overlooked part of how the Stealth rules work.

Unless observers are actively alert, Stealth rolls are for a simple success. Even failure simply makes observers alert. Only alert observers get to try and Notice a Stealth roll (before the final step, as noted under **Sneak Attack**).

Sentries on alert for mundane troops should not count as alert when dealing with invisible or silent foes. If potential attackers are known to use *invisibility* or *silence* (or both) then the guards might be alert for such things.

---

I should also note that you can head to the [PEG forums](https://www.pegforum.com/) to use the Official Answers section and get an official answer from a PEG employee.